# Adding styling information to results from GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

On [this page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/), for instance, we have an example like this:

#### gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "My Homepage",
    description: "This is where I write my thoughts.",
  },
}
```

#### src/pages/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

  const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.site.siteMetadata.description}
    </div>
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        description
      }
    }
  }
`
export default HomePage
```

I understand what is going on, but what if I want to style my `description`? [This tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-six/) talks about how to add a Markdown transformer, but I want to use React-like styling, so my `description` might be in an ideal world:

```
description: "This is where I write my <span className={style.zalgo}>thoughts</span>.",
```

`src/pages/index.module.css` defines the `.zalgo` class as per the Gatsby conventions. This would give me a description like:

> This is where I write my t̜͔̰͎̣̙͔̏̾ͩ̅̂h̹͔̜͆̆̒ͩo̜̠͎̜ͮͯu͗̍̓҉̻̬̼̥͉̖g̘̻̱̙͠ͅͅh̦̘͈̺̯̽ͮ̓͑͆ͧ͞t̹̫̜̲͎̝ͨͣ̈́͢s͖ͯͥͣ.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just send standard html

```
This is where I write my <span class={style.zalgo}>thoughts</span>.
```

and then set the content of an element on the page using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.site.siteMetadata.description }} />
```

Comment: @KenY-N It's only a XSS risk if you are rendering user input. If you are rendering content that you are generating yourself (a blog, etc.) then it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use [StaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/)? inside it's render you will be able apply any styling like in ordinary React